# API equivalent of Backlinks capability from the UI

Tags: notion-api

We have a Contacts database in Notion.  Unfortunately, over time we've created some duplicate contacts.  We're building an integration that combines duplicate contacts.  The logic for properties is quite straightforward, even relations.

The issue for which I'm hoping someone can help is finding pages that link to one of the duplicates outside of database properties (ie. from the body of a page but an @-mention).  In the UI you can see "Backlinks".  I'm hoping there is a way to find inbound links for a page using the API.  Any help would be appreciated.